# Unknown package: mule-module error after running mvn archetype for cloud connector creation via DevKit

Tags: maven, mule, pom.xml, devkit

i've created a new Cloud Connector using DevKit, after running:

```
mvn clean package -Ddevkit.studio.package.skip=false
```

The project shows errors in the pom.file:

```
Project build error: Unknown packaging: mule-module pom.xml /http-https-component
```

And:

```
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.devkit:mule-devkit-maven-plugin:3.4.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre6/../lib/tools.jar   pom.xml /http-https-component
```

This is my entire current pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mulesoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>http-https-component</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule-module</packaging>
    <name>Mule Cloud Connector</name>

    <properties>
        <mule.version>3.4.0</mule.version>
        <mule.devkit.version>3.4.0</mule.devkit.version>
        <junit.version>4.9</junit.version>
        <mockito.version>1.8.2</mockito.version>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.mule.tools.devkit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mule-devkit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${mule.devkit.version}</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.mule.tools.devkit</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>mule-devkit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>attach-test-resources</goal>
                                            <goal>filter-resources</goal>
                                            <goal>generate-sources</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                            <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                            <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                            <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                            <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.devkit</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-devkit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.devkit.version}</version>
            </plugin><plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludePackageNames>org.mule.tooling.ui.contribution:*</excludePackageNames>
                    <docletArtifact>
                        <groupId>org.mule.tools.devkit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mule-devkit-doclet</artifactId>
                        <version>${mule.devkit.version}</version>
                    </docletArtifact>
                    <doclet>org.mule.devkit.doclet.Doclava</doclet>
                    <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}</bootclasspath>
                    <additionalparam>
                        -quiet
                        -federate JDK http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?
                        -federationxml JDK http://doclava.googlecode.com/svn/static/api/openjdk-6.xml
                        -hdf project.artifactId "${project.artifactId}"
                        -hdf project.groupId "${project.groupId}"
                        -hdf project.version "${project.version}"
                        -hdf project.name "${project.name}"
                        -hdf project.repo.name "${project.distributionManagement.repository.name}"
                        -hdf project.repo.id "${project.distributionManagement.repository.id}"
                        -hdf project.repo.url "${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}"
                        -hdf project.snapshotRepo.name "${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.name}"
                        -hdf project.snapshotRepo.id "${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.id}"
                        -hdf project.snapshotRepo.url "${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url}"
                        -d ${project.build.directory}/apidocs
                    </additionalparam>
                    <useStandardDocletOptions>false</useStandardDocletOptions>
                    <additionalJOption>-J-Xmx1024m</additionalJOption>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven-version</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>[3.0.0,)</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                                <requireJavaVersion>
                                    <version>[1.6.0,)</version>
                                </requireJavaVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.devkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-devkit-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.devkit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipse-workbench</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1.M20100826-1330</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipse-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.v20100505</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Snapshots Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus-releases</id>
            <name>CodeHaus Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mulesoft-plugin-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mulesoft-plugin-snapshots</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

This is part of my settings.xml in m2 folder:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>mulesoft-release</id>
      <mirrorOf>muleforge-release</mirrorOf>
      <name>Mulesoft Release Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
      <id>mulesoft-snapshot</id>
      <mirrorOf>muleforge-snapshot</mirrorOf>
      <name>Mulesoft Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The packaging is **mule** not **mule-module**.

EDIT: Also make sure you have `org.mule.tools` in your settings.xml pluginGroups:

```
<pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.mule.tools</pluginGroup>
    ...
</pluginGroups>
```

Comment: Hey David, i don't even have a tag called pluginGroups in the maven repo settings.xml file :S I'm going to add them inside the <settings> tag and outside the others as a new tag group

Comment: Nope, didn't work either :(((( what else could be done? read in many forums and found nothing. There was a person saying it would be a problem with the JRE, that this should be using JDK.

Comment: DevKit 3.4.0 requires Oracle's JDK 1.6. I don't get the `mirrors` definition in your settings file: maybe this is what causes the problem? Otherwise it should work just fine.

Comment: I don't know :( dunno what's wrong with this project... i've tried so many things, there must be something failing. The project doesn't compile because of the pom.xml file.

Comment: Update your question with the current errors, with full stack traces, thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32039/discussion-between-david-dossot-and-msqar)

Comment: @DavidDossot hmm I also get this Project build error. Just tried to compile my new devkit project using -DarchetypeVersion=3.4.0 : Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.devkit:mule-devkit-maven-plugin:3.4.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre6/../lib/tools.jar   pom.xml /http-https-component

Comment: @DavidDossot in my build path I'm pointing to the jdk 1.6 for my JRE system lib, so I can't figure out where this pointing to jre 1.7 is, I'll run a text search

Comment: @DavidDossot if you have assured solution then why don't you share your pom.xml here so that we may get specific path to follow.

Comment: Sure, here is one: https://github.com/mulesoft/redis-connector/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

change AnypointStudio's Default JRE to jdk->jre, For example:

```
old:C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
new:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```html
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.9</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <excludeMuleDependencies>false</excludeMuleDependencies>
    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
    <inclusions>
      <inclusion>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-requester</artifactId>
      </inclusion>
      <inclusion>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-requester</artifactId>
      </inclusion>
      <inclusion>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
      </inclusion>
    </inclusions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```